# Semi-direct products and associated graded Lie algebras

Tags: gr.group-theory, lie-algebras, group-actions, nilpotent-groups, associated-graded

Let $G$ and $H$ be groups and $G\ltimes H$ their semi-direct product given by $f\colon G\to \operatorname{Aut}(H)$ satisfying $f(g)=\operatorname{id}_H$ in $H/[H,H]\,$ for all $g\in G$. In this situation, one can construct the semi-direct product of their associated (to the lower central series) graded Lie algebras by $\operatorname{gr}f\colon \operatorname{gr}G\to \operatorname{Der gr}H$.

**Question:** If $G$ and $H$ is residually nilpotent, does $\operatorname{gr}(G\ltimes H)\cong \operatorname{gr}G\ltimes \operatorname{gr}H$ hold?

One example is pure braid groups and Drinfeld-Kohno Lie algebras: $\mathrm{PB}_{n+1}=\mathrm{PB}_n \ltimes F_n$ and $\mathfrak{p}_{n+1} = \mathfrak{p}_n \ltimes \mathfrak{lie}_n$. $\mathrm{PB}_n$ and free groups are both residually nilpotent, so the nilpotency assumption seems plausible.

Thank you.

Comment: No, just consider $G$ of order 2, $H$ of order 3, and the dihedral group of order 6 as semidirect product: the latter is not even residually nilpotent.

Comment: What is $N$? And are you assuming $G\ltimes H$ is residually nilpotent?

Comment: @Dave Benson That was a typo; $[H,H]$ is the correct one.

Comment: @Dave Benson I'm not assuming residual nilpotency for $G\ltimes H$.

Comment: @YCor Thank you for a comment. In your example, $H$ is abelian and the action is non-trivial, while my assumption says the action is trivial (since $H/[H,H] = H$); so it's not a counter example.

Comment: Correct, this is indeed an important assumption.

Comment: I think this is always true under the condition that $G$ acts trivially on $H/[H,H]$ (this is called an almost direct product).  You don't need the groups at hand to be residually nilpotent. This is due to Falk--Randell (https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01394780) and their motivation was indeed to prove that result for pure braid groups and some of their generalizations.

Comment: If $G$ and $H$ are residually nilpotent, then this shows $G\ltimes H$ is as well.

Comment: Thanks! This answers to all the questions above.